# Is there a way to generate separate TestExecution files when using multiple threads?

Tags: automated-tests, bdd, xunit, specflow

I am attempting to write a tool that will automate the generation of a visual studio test playlist based on failed tests from the spec flow report, we recently increased our testThreadCount to 4 and when using the LivingDocumentation plugin to generate the TestExecution.json file it is only generating a result for 1 in 4 tests and I think this is due to the threadCount so 4 tests are being seen as a single execution.

My aim is to generate a fully qualified test name for each of the failed tests using the TestExecution file but this will not work if I am only generating 25% of the results. Could I ask if anyone has an idea of a workaround for this?

```
<Execution stopAfterFailures="0" testThreadCount="4" testSchedulingMode="Sequential" retryFor="Failing" retryCount="0" />
```

This is our current execution settings in the .srprofile

Answer (score 2):

We made this possible with the latest version of SpecFlow and the SpecFlow+ LivingDoc Plugin.

You can configure the filename for the `TestExecution.json` via specflow.json.
Here is an example:

```json
{
  "livingDocGenerator": {
    "enabled": true,
    "filePath": "TestExecution_{ProcessId}_{ThreadId}.json"
  }
}
```

ProcessId and ThreadId will be replaced with values and you get for every thread a separate `TestExecution.json`.

You can then give the `livingdoc` CLI tool or the Azure DevOps task a list of `TestExecution.jsons`.

Example:

> livingdoc test-assembly BookShop.AcceptanceTests.dll -t TestExecution*.json

This generates you one LivingDoc with all the test execution results combines.

Documentation links:

https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow-livingdoc/en/latest/LivingDocGenerator/Setup-the-LivingDocPlugin.html
https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow-livingdoc/en/latest/Guides/Merging-Multiple-test-results.html

Comment: Thank you for the response Andreas that is really helpful! We were having some trouble installing the latest version of the living Doc plugin due to some version conflicts but I will look into trying the upgrade now.

Comment: If you still have problems @HermanCodes, please contact our support.